# How to reenable formio submit button?

Tags: form-submit, formio

I'm using formio with angular to render a custom form I've built - https://help.form.io/developer/info/angular/

I'm using the following to catch the submission and call my own logic, however the submit button stays disabled. I'm not actually using the formio server side so how do I re-enable the submit button without changing the source code? Is there an undocumented event for form submission success? I've tried also binding to 'formSubmission' event.

```
$scope.$on('formSubmit', function(err, data) {
    event.preventDefault();
    submitForm();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else struggling with this you can call 'submitDone' but you need to $broadcast from your controller, not $emit ( $emit goes up the $scope chain, broadcast goes down )

```
$scope.$on('formSubmit', function(err, data) {
    event.preventDefault();
    submitForm();
}
function submitForm() {
    var error = doStuff();
    if ( error ) {
        $scope.$broadcast('submitError', error);
    } else {
        $scope.$broadcast('submitDone', 'Success');
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't have answered it better myself. Thanks!

Comment: how to get form io button action?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using pure javascript, trigger the event with "emit" and intercept with "on", try this

```
 formio.emit('submitError', res);// formio.emit('submitError', res);
```

The button with red background will be displayed by default
[image]

To intercept the event triggered by the emit, do the code below

```
formio.on('submitDone', function(res) { /*your code here*/ }
```